# Python request mock with zipped files

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-requests, request

I have 2 services:

1. First one allows upload of certain data, then it zips it up, and packs it into a POST request, together with some additional numerical data, and sends it to service no. 2.
2. Second one receives this POST request, and then pushes it through a chain of responsibility to process data contained in it.

I am in the process of writing unit tests for service no. 2, and I have no idea on how to mock an actual POST request, in a form in which in would be received by it (with all data serialized into a JSON etc.).
A lot of the tutorials I have seen online just show us how to mock an API call with @patch decorator and Mock objects from the unittest package, but none really show how to create a Request object, as it is seen by the receiving service.

The code on **Service One** constructs the Request call in the following way:

```
headers = {'content_type':'application/zip', 'one': case.one, 'two': case.two, 'three': case.three}
file_buffer = # In-memory zip-file
additional_attrs = # A Python dictionary 

response = requests.Session().post(
    url, 
    files = {'data': file_buffer},
    headers=headers, 
    data={'additional_attrs': json.dumps(additional_attrs, default=json_serial),
    'some_dataframe': some_dataframe.to_json(date_format='iso')}
)
```

How can I construct an outcome of a request above, as it is received on the **Service Two** end?